# How to make a multi-colour dash in WPF (for a polygon)

Tags: wpf

I am able to make a dashed Polygon in WPF using the StrokeDashedArray property, i.e.,

```
Polygon maskingPolygon = new Polygon()
maskingPolygon.Stroke = Brushes.White;
maskingPolygon.StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() {2,2};
```

However, I can't seem to make a dash pattern that rotates through a few different colours. I want to create a dash that alternates between black and white. I hope for functionality like this:

```
Polygon maskingPolygon = new Polygon()
maskingPolygon.StrokeDashArray = new Dictionary<int,Brush>();
maskingPolygon.StrokeDashArray.Add(2, White);
maskingPolygon.StrokeDashArray.Add(2, Black);
```

I need to use alternating black and white dashes because the polygon needs to be visible if overlaid on an arbitrary photo.

I have illustrated the effect I desire below using red instead of white for visibility.

[image: multi-colour dash illustration]

The hacky way I could do it is inherit from the polygon class and create two polygons from the same set of  points, one with dashes overlaid with one without dashes. But that's clumsy.

Comment: I don't think your hacky way is actually that clumsy.  WPF is good for creating new controls by composing existing ones.  What are you worried about?

Comment: Let's call my hacked polygon class DashedPolygon, inherited from Polygon. It will be composed of a plain background Polygon (with a black stroke colour) with another (white) polygon on top of it. 

1) I'm not sure where to put the overlaid polygon so it is display when the DashedPolygon instance is added to the canvas.

2) When points are added to the DashedPolygon, how do I listen so that they're added to the overlaid polygon? The polygon will be change frequently in my instance.

Comment: Why not simply have two Polygon instances and bind their `Points` property to the same Point collection?